# Implementing Chromecast without using AppCompat

Tags: android, chromecast

I'm writing an Android plugin (for Unity) that implements Chromecast and it's working fine, as long as AppCompatActivity is used and also the theme @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

However changing the Activity to AppCompatActivity creates a number of other problems, so I'm looking for a way to avoid that (if possible). But I can't seem to find a way to do that. I get the following errror:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: background can not be translucent: #0
```

And the only way I see to solve it is to switch to appcompat.

This is how the code looks like now:

fragment1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:name="com.app.FragmentButtons"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

buttons.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/buttons_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="right"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteButton
        android:id="@+id/media_route_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:mediaRouteTypes="user"
        android:visibility="gone"

        android:background="#000000"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

And the error is thrown on this line:

```
LinearLayout fragment1 = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(UnityPlayer.currentActivity, R.layout.fragment1, null);
```

The app is currently using this theme: @android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen

Is there a way to fix this error (and implement Chromecast) without using AppCompatActivity?

Thanks!